# How to pass difference type of model in view?

Tags: asp.net, view, model, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I pass the difference type of model (depend on the the returning in the controller) to view?

**Here is my Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            if (isAdmin(Session["username"].ToString()))
            {
                return View(db.Branches.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                int id = db.Users.Find(Session["username"]).branch_id;
                return View(db.Branches.Find(id));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it may return difference type to view depend on user is admin or not.

And this View is just handled for the returning of List Branches , not the single Branches

```
@model IEnumerable<Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Models.Branch>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.create_date)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.create_date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm"})
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-white btn-sm"})
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-white btn-sm"})
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

I have tried this but it just works when I return both types of model. Not the thing I want.

```
 @model Tuple<IEnumerable<Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Models.Branch>, Inspinia_MVC5_SeedProject.Models.Branch>
```

How can I handle this thing without creating another view for the other model type? Thanks and I will be very appropriate if anyone can help me this. You may not need for posting all code to me, just some keywords or tell me how can I do solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `View` is not going to change and will remain exactly the same for both *User* as well as *Admin* then your only issue is that the `View` accepts a collection, so the solution is pass single object also as collection:-

```
else
{
     int id = db.Users.Find(Session["username"]).branch_id;
     return View(db.Branches.Where(x => x.id == id));
}
```

This ensures your return type id `IEnumerable<T>` and not a single object and thus your *View* can parse it.

Comment: OMG. You saved my life. I have searched it for over 3 hours without any ideas, and you just solve it within not over 5 minutes. Thank you so so  much.